# Sublime: Running script from cursor until begin script without select lines

Tags: r, sublimetext2, sublimerepl

I am using Sublime to work with R via Repl, all works fine...

But I wonder if its possible run commands lines from cursor until the begin of script without select lines above the cursor...

Because when I select lines above the cursor to run script, the cursor dont back to my last place that I was working and sometimes its dificult find my last place to continue with my work...

I am not expert programer and probably I miss a lot of tips to do it.

Below the cursor exist other command lines that I dont wanna run:

```
rm(list=ls()) 
library(dplyr)
library(readxl)
library(rtf)
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)

df=mtcars

View(df)

| #Cursor here, only run codes above it

str(df)
summary(df)
names(df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select the lines, hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> and either use <kbd>↑</kbd> to select all the above lines, or simply click at the beginning with your mouse. The keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>,</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd> (hit Ctrl+comma, release, and hit S) will eval the selection in SublimeREPL. Once you switch back to your code with the selection, simply hit <kbd>→</kbd> (right arrow) and your cursor will be back where it was at the end of the selection.

To answer your question: No, there is no way to evaluate all the content above your cursor in a REPL via a command or keyboard shortcut. You can evaluate the whole file, the current line, the current selection, or the current block of code.

Comment: Thanks @MattDMo, could you give me an example to run a current block of code?